Pullback of Hopf fibration through inversion
Consider the Hopf fibration constructed as a complex line bundle $\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{CP}^1\cong S^2$ via the standard quotient.
I am confused about the vector bundle one would get by taking the pullback through the inversion map $$S^2\to S^2: x\to -x.$$
On the one hand, since the inversion is a diffeomorphism of the $2$-sphere, I expect the pullback to be isomorphic to the original Hopf fibration. (as is discussed in this question).
On the other hand, the inversion map is of degree $-1$ and so it should change the sign of the first Chern class from $c_1=1$ for the Hopf fibration to $c_1=-1$ for the pullback bundle. Since the two bundles have different Chern classes, they cannot be isomorphic.
I'd like to understand which of the above two reasonings  (or both) is wrong, and why. My understanding of vector bundles is bit spotty so I suspect I'm missing a simple yet crucial point here.

I think you're getting caught up on the word "isomorphism" here. For vector bundles there's essentially two notions of isomorphism: The more general one is that two vector bundles $p_1\colon E_1 \to X_1$ and $p_2\colon E_2 \to X_2$ over possibly different base spaces are isomorphic if there exists an invertible map between them, where a map is a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    E_1 @>\alpha>> E_2 \\
    @Vp_1VV @VVp_2V \\
    X_1 @>>\beta> X_2
\end{CD}
with $\alpha$ fibrewise linear.
This specializes to a notion of isomorphism of vector bundles over the same base space by requiring that $\beta$ be the identity. Only for this second notion is it true that the Chern classes of isomorphic bundles are the same; for the first notion this statement doesn't even parse because $X_1$ and $X_2$ need not be the same space. What's true, however, is that the Chern classes of $E_1$ and $E_2$ will be related by $\beta^*\colon H^*(X_2) \to H^*(X_1)$ and its inverse.
Now you should see what the issue is: You seem to be implicitly referring to this second notion of isomorphism and therefore assuming the Chern classes should be equal when in fact your isomorphism is by construction of the first form, with $\beta$ a non-trivial automorphism, so even though the base spaces are the same you will find the Chern classes related by $\beta^*$.

As a specific follow-up example, would it then be correct to say that the Hopf fibration and its dual/conjugate bundle are related by an isomorphism of the first kind (through inversion) but not of the second? Since in that case an isomorphism fixing the base space would require an anti-linear map between the fibers?

Yes, that would be correct.
